# Почему нету init в eel?

Tags: python, python-3.x, eel

Пробую запустить свою страницу в виде программы с веб-интерфейсом. Для этого использую `python 3.8.1` с библиотекой `eel`. Но, к сожалению, Python не хочет с ним работать(

**Ошибка:**

```
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'eel' has no attribute 'init' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

**Код**

```
import eel
eel.init('web')
eel.start('index.html', size=(700, 700))
```

Comment: Скрипт с тем кодом называется `eel.py`?

Comment: @gil9red кстати частая ошибка, я сам себе так стрелял в ноги :D

Comment: @gil9red, блин, точно XD Забыл что нельзя называть программу как модуль XD Спасибо большое)

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте директорию проекта на наличие `eel.py`, созданный вами лично, если найдете - переименуйте в что нибудь другое.

Также устанавливайте все библиотеки через `pip`:
`pip install Eel`

Потом попробуйте ввести следующее в консоли `python3` :

```
import eel
dir(eel)
```

Вам вернется список и в нём можно будет найти `init()`, если не найдете - переустанавливайте пакет.